# How can i merge 2 different commits?

Tags: git, github

i did `git add .` followed by `git commit` (first_commit) and i added all files and directories without adding the unwanted directories to gitignore, after that i did updated gitignore and commit   (second_commit) the change.

my problem is i want to rollback before the 'first_commit' and merge it with the 'second_commit' after that i want to merge the 'first_commit' with this result.

is it possible to do so ??

i didnt try anything, the repo is not that important i can create new repo and push the last local version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+combine+last+two+commits